# Excel Deleting rows with quantity only zero

Tags: vba

I am trying to delete Rows have only a quantity of "0" using VBA but the code that i am using is deleting everything that has a "0" in the quantity. like 600 will be deleted because it has a "0"

This the code below.

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim SrchRng

    Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("G1", ActiveSheet.Range("G65536").End(xlUp))
    Do
        Set c = SrchRng.Find("0", LookIn:=x1Values)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete
    Loop While Not c Is Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: As @mehow discovered in my answer (which started out with a copy/paste from your code) you have `x1Values` (number 1) instead of `xlValues` (letter L) in your `LookIn:=x1Values`. If you don't set `Option Explicit`, it will quietly set a new variable to a value of zero. Not sure what that does to the search command. Yet another reason why you need `Option Explicit` to catch typos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

`Set c = SrchRng.Find("0", LookIn:=x1Values)`

To this (add the `LookAt` argument and correct the typo in the `LookIn` argument):

`Set c = SrchRng.Find("0", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)`

[Documentation for the `Range.Find` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx), provides some information about the optional arguments.

However, I think the range.find method is expensive. A simple iteration might be faster:

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim i as Long
    Dim SrchRng

    Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("G1", ActiveSheet.Range("G65536").End(xlUp))
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = SrchRng.Cells.Count to 1 Step -1
        Set c = SrchRng.Cells(i)
        If c.Value = "0" Then c.EntireRow.Delete
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: @Gabriel I'm assuming you're trying the second method. Which line is causing the error?

Comment: @DavidZemens THIS LINE Set c = SrchRng.Find("0", LookIn:=x1Values, LookAt:=xlWhole)

Comment: You have a typo in your code I think, it says `x1Values` where it should say `xlValues` (not the "1" versus a lower-case "L"

Comment: No problem! Please do consider marking the answer as "Accepted" if it has solved the problem for you.  Cheers!

Comment: +1 for "However, I think the range.find method is expensive. A simple iteration might be faster:"

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an option:

```
Set c = SrchRng.Find("0", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

To look at the "whole" cell

Comment: @mehow good catch on the typo. Without `Option Explicit`, these things can happen (and quietly give the wrong result - `LookAt:=0` ... I have no idea what that will do.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large data set this is fast

```
Sub DeleteRows()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim lCol As Long
Dim lRow As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("mySheetName")

 lCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
 lRow = ws.Range("G" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With ws
  .AutoFilterMode = False
  .Range("A1", Cells(lRow, lCol)).Cells.AutoFilter
  .Range("A1", Cells(lRow, lCol)).Cells.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="0"
  .UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1).Rows.Delete
  .AutoFilterMode = False
  .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1).Resize(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).EntireRow.Delete
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```